# Adal-angular app token with secret

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that gets bearer token from Azure ad with adal-angular.
I can ask questions to graph-api to get the data i want with that token.
But now i want to change that data. For that i need an app token from azure AD.
Graph api resource is https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/educationschool_update

My app is an React app that uses adal-angular.

My app have an secret to do this.
My question(s) is, can Adal -angular get me this app-token? And if its possible, how can it do that?
below is my config for adal angular. client_secret is what im trying to get to work..

```
window.authContext = new AuthContext({
  tenant: 'xxxxx',
  clientId: 'xxxx',
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
  client_secret : 'APP SECRET HERE!?!?!?!?!?!?',
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
});
```

this is my method to get token for the logged in person.

```
aquireToken() {
        let header = null;
        window.authContext.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', (error, token) => {
            header = {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            }
        });
        return header;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible from the web client (UI loaded in the browser) because according to Azure AD CORS policy only Authorize endpoint is open to the web clients and you can't send client_secret to the Authorize endpoint. There is no such parameter according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

I hope it helps even it came 6 months after asking :)